# Android devices don't show up on Chrome's "send to your devices"

Tags: chrome-for-android

I'm trying to share a link between my desktop and Android, I'm using Chrome on both and am fully synced.

On my Android, when I tap the link -> Share -> Send to your devices, I only see my laptop whereas I want to open a link on my desktop.

In *Chrome History*, under *Tabs from other devices*, the list appears to be empty.

Why is it not there?

Comment: From your desktop's Chrome, browse to `chrome://sync-internals/` - Sync Node Browser - Device Info. Do you see your Android device from there? Or, perhaps more simply, are the tabs from your Android's Chrome shown on `chrome://history/syncedTabs`?

Comment: @AndrewT. that's the data in the table in the Device Info row: `Device Info | 1 | 1 | Error: WriteModifications@../../components/sync/model_impl/model_type_store_backend.cc:208, datatype error was encountered: Corruption: block checksum mismatch| Failed | Group Passive`

Comment: *Stop sync* and *Request start* didn't change much.

Comment: Synced tabs empty

Answer (score 0):

After re-installing Chrome, issue was gone.
But at the uninstallation, I had to check the *Also delete your browsing history data?* option (I tried without and it didn't work).

HTH

[image]